# Return a recordset from vertica database

Tags: vertica

What i realised is in vertica SQL functions do not return a record set and only scalar functions are available.

other RDBMS concepts that i thought of:
user defined data type,
reference cursors,
return temp table,
table type

Is there any workaround for this in vertica?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something called [External Procedures](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ExtendingHPVertica/ExternalProcedures/UsingExternalProcedures.htm).

This will allow for a result set to be returned when called from an external shell script.

Comment: "The external procedure cannot communicate back to HP Vertica".I wanted something like table type function or a stored procedure which makes use of table type to return values

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what are your exact requirements, you could create a user-defined transform function (UDTF) or a user-defined load (UDL), also called a "source". The differences are explained [in the manual](http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ExtendingHPVertica/UDx/TypesOfUDFs.htm%3FTocPath%3DExtending%2520HP%2520Vertica%7CDeveloping%2520User%2520Defined%2520Extensions%2520(UDxs)%7C_____1)